# Batch crop pictures in Photoshop with human in the loop

Tags: batch-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to crop a batch of pictures but with no fixed crop region. For the user it should be just the following steps

1. image opens automatically
2. user selects crop region end presses enter
3. image will be saved and closes

However, with the normal Photoshop Action Recording I can't reach that goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically just have to klick here to toggle the dialog on:
[image: Action Toggle Dialog]